# python pandas problem for regular expression

Tags: python

The code `df.loc[df["University"].str.contains("^s[a-z]"),regex=True]`  gives me the error below:

```bash
File "/tmp/ipykernel_27/251161980.py", line 7
    df.loc[df["University"].str.contains("^s[a-z]"), regex=True]
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the `regex=True` in the `.contains()` parenthesis. The correct code may look like this:

```py
df.loc[df["University"].str.contains("^s[a-z]", regex=True)]
```

I strongly suggest understanding the code instead of just trying different things. For example, the `regex=True` is a method parameter. It should be between the parentheses to be used in the `.contains()` method. Also the `[]` brackets for the pandas DataFrame is trying to capture the data that contains the regex provided. So it can not contain `, regex=True` itself. The correct code is provided above.